# Cakephp 3 pass collection to paginate

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I having trouble with the following:

i created a new collection from an exist entity(Test) and add additional field(avaliable)
TestModel:

```
 $avaliable=array(1,0,1,1,1,0);
    //Test has no avaliable field originally        
    $tests=(new Collection($tests->insert('avaliable',$avaliable);
```

when i want to pass this for paginate the page:

```
$test = $this->paginate($tests);
```

than i got this error:

Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\ResultSet::alias()

The reason could be that the original Test entity has no avaliable field so thats why i got this error

Comment: You have three open parentheses there and only one close. Copy and paste your actual code for best help.

Answer (score 0):

The API's documentation of cake php say's:

```
paginate(
  Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface|Cake\Datasource\QueryInterface 
  $object  
  array $settings [] )`
```

The `paginate()` don't expect other types of objects different of these two.

By and sorry for my poor english

The Api documentation link:

[Cakephp 3 paginate()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Controller.Component.PaginatorComponent.html#_paginate)